# Descolocación en proyecto web

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hice unos cambios en mi proyecto, y cuando me quise dar cuenta, todo se descolocó. Como no pensé que se iba a liar tanto, no hice copia, y bueno, intento cambiar cosas y nada funciona.

Ahora mismo está así el código:

```css
::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
  color: white;
  background: #8d33ff;;
}

::selection {
  color: white;
  background: #8d33ff;;
}

body {
 font-family: Verdana;
 background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1206/1206290.png");
 width: 100%;
 background-size: 100px 80px;
}

/* Redimensión */

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#menu {
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
}
#menu a {
 background-color: none;
 padding:10px;
 margin-top:0px;
 display:block;
 text-align: center;
 width:100%;
 color:white;
}

#portada {
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:0 20px;
}
#lateral {
 background-color:none;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:15px;
 margin-top:7px;
 text-align:center;
}

#contenido2 {
 background-color:none;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:15px;
 margin-top:7px;
 text-align:center;
}

/* Estructura flex */

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: none;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: none;
  color: black;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

/* Nav bar */

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* Galería */

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.img {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.img:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 31%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* Dropdown */

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
   overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}

/* Otros */

.lateral {
 background-color: FloralWhite;
}

p {
    background: rgba(236, 223, 255, 0.5);
}

a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container" id="portada">
  <div style="flex-grow: 10">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-banner-gatos-lindos-dicen-hola_45130-353.jpg"
  width="100%" height="300px;">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- class="active" -->

<div class="navbar" id="menu">
  <a class="active" href="./index.php">
      <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: white">home</i>Inicio</a>
      
  <a href="">Gato1</a>
      
  <a href="">Gato2</a>
      
  <a href="">Gato3</a>
     
      <div class="dropdown" style="float: right;">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Buscar 
      <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: white; vertical-align:middle">search</i>
    </button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar..." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
            <a href="#gato1">Gato1</a>
            <a href="#gato2">Gato2</a>
            <a href="#gato3">Gato3</a>
            <a href="#gato4">Gato4</a>
            <a href="#gato5">Gato5</a>
            <a href="#gato6">Gato6</a>
            <a href="#gato7">Gato7</a>
    </div>
    
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="flex-container" id="lateral"> 
 <div style="flex-grow: 1">
      
 <p>Somos unos gatos adorables de prueba :D</p>
            
    </div>
  
  </div> 
    
 <div style="flex-grow: 9"> 

    <div class="responsive">
  <img src="https://www.hola.com/imagenes/estar-bien/20180831128704/ronroneo-gatos-causas/0-595-638/gato-ronroneo-1-t.jpg?filter=w600&filter=ds75" alt="Gato2" width="300" height="200">
  <div class="desc">Hola soy otro gato</div>
 </div>

     <div class="responsive">
  <a href="gato2.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.hola.com/imagenes/estar-bien/20180831128704/ronroneo-gatos-causas/0-595-638/gato-ronroneo-1-t.jpg?filter=w600&filter=ds75" alt="Gato2" width="300" height="200">
    </a>
  <div class="desc">Hola soy otro gato</div>
 </div>
  </div>

 <div class="responsive">
  <a href="gato3.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.promiau.com/static/img/img_blog/Thelazia_un_gusano_que_puede_parasitar_los_ojos_del_gato.jpeg" alt="Gato3" width="300" height="200">
    </a>
  <div class="desc">Y otro gato</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="responsive">
  <a href="gato3.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.promiau.com/static/img/img_blog/Thelazia_un_gusano_que_puede_parasitar_los_ojos_del_gato.jpeg" alt="Gato3" width="300" height="200">
    </a> 
  <div class="desc">Y otro gato</div>
 </div>
  
  <div class="responsive">
  <a href="gato.jpg">
  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/410/cpsprodpb/8536/production/_103520143_gettyimages-908714708.jpg" alt="Gato1" width="300" height="200">
    </a>
  <div class="desc">Hola soy un gato</div>
  </div>
 
 <div class="responsive">
  <a href="gato2.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.hola.com/imagenes/estar-bien/20180831128704/ronroneo-gatos-causas/0-595-638/gato-ronroneo-1-t.jpg?filter=w600&filter=ds75" alt="Gato2" width="300" height="200">
    </a>
  <div class="desc">Hola soy otro gato</div>
 </div>
</body>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>

</html>
```

No recuerdo ahora más que añadir el `dropdown` del menú, y quizá intentar arreglar el `responsive` de las imágenes.  No sé cuando se puso así de raro todo.

Lo que se ha descolocado:

- **Menú de navegación**. Ahora está vertical, antes horizontal y no logro cambiarlo.
- En el **dropdown del menú**, las opciones que hay al desplegar aparecen con color blanco, por mucho que cambio a color negro en el css a la clase, no cambia.
- El texto que hay debajo de las imágenes tenía un fondo blanco que no sé cuándo desapareció.
- Las **flexbox** son ignoradas. El proyecto tiene la siguiente estructura, y la ignora completamente.

[image: estructura web]

Para el primer punto, intenté volver a hacer todo desde el principio. Literalmente copié todo el código que salía bien y lo pegué, modificando lo correspondiente, y aún así seguía en vertical.

Para el segundo punto, añadí al `.dropdown` color negro. Quité el `color: white` que tenía la clase `.dropdown, .dropbtn`, pero nada. Al `.dropdown-content` igual, `color: black` y nada. 
No sé que se supone que tengo que modificar para cambiar eso.

El tercer punto probablemente haya sido el causante de todo. Me hago un lío intentando que las imágenes sean `responsive` sin conseguir del todo el [punto](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_ex_images_responsive) deseado que se consigue en los [tutoriales](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_image2) que veo, siempre terminan deformándose o saliéndose el texto o cualquier otro problema.

Comment: Hola Lucía. Visita [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dlunamontilla/pen/bGNXjVY?editors=1000). Allí te coloqué un ejemplo con tus gatos para que puedas hacer una cuadrícula totalmente _Responsive_. Tanto de la forma antigua como de la forma moderna. No te lo coloco en las respuesta por el momento porque puede resultar muy extensa la explicación. Lo revisas y me comentas.

Comment: Si hayas útil la solución que encuentres en [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dlunamontilla/pen/bGNXjVY?editors=1000) puede considerar copiar el código y explicarlo en una pregunta y respuesta que te puedas plantear.

Comment: Voy a probarla y ahora te digo, ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: Otra cosa, puedes desarrollar cada parte de la página en forma de componentes. Es decir, que las cabeceras, que es donde debe ir el _banner_ y el _menú de navegación_ el contenido, las secciones y el pie de página las desarrolles como componentes independientes para que te sea más fácil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando suceden este tipo de cosas no hay que ponerse nervioso y, aunque cueste, tratarlo como una oportunidad para aprender o reforzar el conocimiento que se tiene sobre lo que estás maquetando.

Trataré de responderte punto por punto, desglosándolos para finalmente colocar un **snniped** con todo los puntos arreglados.

1. El problema lo tienes en el tamaño que le has dado a los `<a>` de tu elemento `#menu`. Al darles un `width: 100%` estás diciéndoles que ocupen la totalidad de lo que ocupe su padre, ocasionando que estos salgan verticalmente.
2. Este se trata de un problema de pura *especifidad* de **CSS**. Estás tratando de afectar a un elemento con la regla `.dropdown-content a` que ya está siendo afectado por otra regla que prevalece sobre esa `#menu a`. En la *especifidad* llamar a un elemento por la ID tiene más peso que hacerlo por la clase, por lo que para afectar correctamente al elemento con tu regla la cambie por `#myDropdown a` (te recomiendo que leas sobre la [especifidad CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad)).
3. No tienes ninguna regla que afecte al `background-color` de ese elemento. Con añadírsela a la regla `div.desc` que tienes definida, te valdría.
4. A mi juicio este solo punto requería una análisis aparte debido a su longitud. Yo abriría una sola pregunta solamente con este.

```css
::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
  color: white;
  background: #8d33ff;;
}

::selection {
  color: white;
  background: #8d33ff;;
}

body {
 font-family: Verdana;
 background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1206/1206290.png");
 width: 100%;
 background-size: 100px 80px;
}

/* Redimensión */

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#menu {
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
}
#menu a {
 background-color: none;
 padding:10px;
 margin-top:0px;
 display:block;
 text-align: center;
 color:white;
}

#portada {
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:0 20px;
}
#lateral {
 background-color:none;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:15px;
 margin-top:7px;
 text-align:center;
}

#contenido2 {
 background-color:none;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:15px;
 margin-top:7px;
 text-align:center;
}

/* Estructura flex */

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: none;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: none;
  color: black;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

/* Nav bar */

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* Galería */

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.img {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.img:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: white;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 31%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* Dropdown */

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
   overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

#myDropdown a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}

/* Otros */

.lateral {
 background-color: FloralWhite;
}

p {
    background: rgba(236, 223, 255, 0.5);
}

a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container" id="portada">
  <div style="flex-grow: 10">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-banner-gatos-lindos-dicen-hola_45130-353.jpg"
  width="100%" height="300px;">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- class="active" -->

<div class="navbar" id="menu">
  <a class="active" href="./index.php">
      <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: white">home</i>Inicio</a>
      
  <a href="">Gato1</a>
      
  <a href="">Gato2</a>
      
  <a href="">Gato3</a>
     
      <div class="dropdown" style="float: right;">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Buscar 
      <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: white; vertical-align:middle">search</i>
    </button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar..." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
            <a href="#gato1">Gato1</a>
            <a href="#gato2">Gato2</a>
            <a href="#gato3">Gato3</a>
            <a href="#gato4">Gato4</a>
            <a href="#gato5">Gato5</a>
            <a href="#gato6">Gato6</a>
            <a href="#gato7">Gato7</a>
    </div>
    
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="flex-container" id="lateral"> 
 <div style="flex-grow: 1">
      
 <p>Somos unos gatos adorables de prueba :D</p>
            
    </div>
  
  </div> 
    
 <div style="flex-grow: 9"> 

    <div class="responsive">
  <img src="https://www.hola.com/imagenes/estar-bien/20180831128704/ronroneo-gatos-causas/0-595-638/gato-ronroneo-1-t.jpg?filter=w600&filter=ds75" alt="Gato2" width="300" height="200">
  <div class="desc">Hola soy otro gato</div>
 </div>

     <div class="responsive">
  <a href="gato2.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.hola.com/imagenes/estar-bien/20180831128704/ronroneo-gatos-causas/0-595-638/gato-ronroneo-1-t.jpg?filter=w600&filter=ds75" alt="Gato2" width="300" height="200">
    </a>
  <div class="desc">Hola soy otro gato</div>
 </div>
  </div>

 <div class="responsive">
  <a href="gato3.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.promiau.com/static/img/img_blog/Thelazia_un_gusano_que_puede_parasitar_los_ojos_del_gato.jpeg" alt="Gato3" width="300" height="200">
    </a>
  <div class="desc">Y otro gato</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="responsive">
  <a href="gato3.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.promiau.com/static/img/img_blog/Thelazia_un_gusano_que_puede_parasitar_los_ojos_del_gato.jpeg" alt="Gato3" width="300" height="200">
    </a> 
  <div class="desc">Y otro gato</div>
 </div>
  
  <div class="responsive">
  <a href="gato.jpg">
  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/410/cpsprodpb/8536/production/_103520143_gettyimages-908714708.jpg" alt="Gato1" width="300" height="200">
    </a>
  <div class="desc">Hola soy un gato</div>
  </div>
 
 <div class="responsive">
  <a href="gato2.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.hola.com/imagenes/estar-bien/20180831128704/ronroneo-gatos-causas/0-595-638/gato-ronroneo-1-t.jpg?filter=w600&filter=ds75" alt="Gato2" width="300" height="200">
    </a>
  <div class="desc">Hola soy otro gato</div>
 </div>
</body>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>

</html>
```

Para finalizar, te daría un consejo.: **El inspector de elementos de las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador es tu amigo.** Aprender a usarlo es clave para aprender a maquetar.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! La aplicaré y a ver si doy con solucionar de nuevo el flexbox, si no, ya recurriré a preguntar por aquí

Comment: Faltaban algunos cierres de `divs` y eso causaba la descolocación de todo, los añadí ¡y ya está todo solucionado!

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a la respuesta de [@phpMyGuel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/41639/phpmyguel) y el comentario de [@David E. Luna M.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/67242/david-e-luna-m), he conseguido resolver todo lo que tenía pendiente.

Haciendo uso de los `grid` logré algo incluso mejor que lo que tenía, modificando así el tamaño que se quiera y haciendo que no se distorsionen.

Finalmente ha quedado así el código completo:

```css
::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
  color: white;
  background: #8d33ff;;
}

::selection {
  color: white;
  background: #8d33ff;;
}

body {
 font-family: Verdana;
 background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1206/1206290.png");
 width: 100%;
 background-size: 100px 80px;
}

/* Redimensión */

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#menu {
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
}
#menu a {
 background-color: none;
 display:flex;
 text-align: center;
 color:white;
  }

#portada {
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:0 20px;
}
#lateral {
 background-color:none;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:15px;
 margin-top:7px;
 text-align:center;
}

#contenido2 {
 background-color:none;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:15px;
 margin-top:7px;
 text-align:center;
}

/* Estructura flex */

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: none;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: none;
  color: black;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

/* Nav bar */

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* Galería */

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.img {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.img:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: white;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 31%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* Dropdown */

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
   overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

#myDropdown a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}

/* Otros */

.lateral {
 background-color: FloralWhite;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columnas), 1fr);
  
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  max-width: 1200px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.grid__item {
  padding-top: 85%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.grid__img {
  --object-fit: cover;
  --object-position: center center;
}

.grid__img {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  object-fit: var(--object-fit);
  object-position: var(--object-position);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid__img,
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}

/* Cantidad de columnas en función
de la pantalla: */
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .grid {
    --columnas: 3;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width:599px) {
  .grid {
    --columnas: 2;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 399px) {
  .grid {
    --columnas: 1;
  }
}

.caption {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  min-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.limpiar {
  clear: both;
}

p {
    background: rgba(236, 223, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container" id="portada">
  <div style="flex-grow: 10">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-banner-gatos-lindos-dicen-hola_45130-353.jpg"
  width="100%" height="300px;">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- class="active" -->

<div class="navbar" id="menu">
  <a class="active" href="./index.php">
      <i class="material-icons" id="icono" style="font-size:24px; color: white">home</i>Inicio</a>
      
  <a href="">
      <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: white">home</i>Gato1</a>
      
  <a href="">
      <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: white">home</i>Gato2</a>
           
  <a href="">
      <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: white">home</i>Gato3</a>
     
      <div class="dropdown" style="float: right;">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Buscar 
      <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: white; vertical-align:middle">search</i>
    </button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar..." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
            <a href="#gato1">Gato1</a>
            <a href="#gato2">Gato2</a>
            <a href="#gato3">Gato3</a>
            <a href="#gato4">Gato4</a>
            <a href="#gato5">Gato5</a>
            <a href="#gato6">Gato6</a>
            <a href="#gato7">Gato7</a>
    </div>
    
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="flex-container" id="lateral"> 

 <div style="flex-grow: 1">
      
 <p>Somos unos gatos adorables de prueba :D</p>
            
  </div>
    
 <div style="flex-grow: 9"> 
    
  <div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item">
    <img  class="grid__img" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/410/cpsprodpb/8536/production/_103520143_gettyimages-908714708.jpg" alt="">
    
    <div class="caption">
      Texto a colocar
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="grid__item">
    <img  class="grid__img" src="https://www.hola.com/imagenes/estar-bien/20180831128704/ronroneo-gatos-causas/0-595-638/gato-ronroneo-1-t.jpg?filter=w600&filter=ds75" alt="">
    
    <div class="caption">
      Texto a colocar
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="grid__item">
    <img  class="grid__img" src="https://www.promiau.com/static/img/img_blog/Thelazia_un_gusano_que_puede_parasitar_los_ojos_del_gato.jpeg" alt="">
    
    <div class="caption">
      Texto a colocar
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="grid__item">
    <img  class="grid__img" src="https://www.promiau.com/static/img/img_blog/Thelazia_un_gusano_que_puede_parasitar_los_ojos_del_gato.jpeg" alt="">
    
    <div class="caption">
      Texto a colocar
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="grid__item">
    <img  class="grid__img" src="https://www.hola.com/imagenes/estar-bien/20180831128704/ronroneo-gatos-causas/0-595-638/gato-ronroneo-1-t.jpg?filter=w600&filter=ds75">
    
    <div class="caption">
      Texto a colocar
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="grid__item">
    <img  class="grid__img" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/410/cpsprodpb/8536/production/_103520143_gettyimages-908714708.jpg">
    
    <div class="caption">
      Texto a colocar
    </div>
    <div class="limpiar"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</body>

<script>

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>

</html>
```